# is it possible to write the hashed value of a cookie to a header in haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I am relatively new to using haproxy, and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use a consistent hashing algorithm to hash a cookie value in to a separate header. This seems very similar to how you would use a consistent `hash-type` (http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-hash-type) for load balancing, but I don't see how you could put the output of that hashing in to a header for backend servers to see.

My use case is that I have a 'uuid' cookie which I want to use to assign users to a pool 1-100 to use in A/B (/C/D... etc) tests. Today we do this in a nodejs app, but we are adding new backends and we want to avoid implementing the same hashing in multiple languages.

I'm currently using haproxy 1.8. I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 http-request set-header header_name %[req.cook(your_cookie),sdbm,mod(100)]
```

Comment: thanks @nuster, this is most of what i am looking for. is it possible to modulo the resulting value in haproxy, to get a number in a fixed range? (ie, between 1-100)

Comment: @mike yes you can use `http-request set-header aaa %[req.cook(bbb),sdbm,mod(100)]`